# How to do : "Between TODAY AND TODAY-7"?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find the account created for the current day, et for the last 7 days.

To find my results for today, it works, and I do this :

```
SELECT * FROM `account` where DATE(created_at) = DATE(NOW())
```

But I don't know how to do to get the last 7days account.

I tried something like this, but without success :

```
SELECT * FROM `account` where DATE(created_at) BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) AND DATE(NOW()-7)
```

Have you an idea ?

Comment: Reference: [mySQL Time and Date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

in mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM `account` 
WHERE DATE(created_at) > (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: -1 This is _not_ "between today and 7 days ago". This is "after 7 days ago" which may include future dates.

Comment: if you have future dates in a column which should contain a date when something was created then something different is very wrong anyway. but you are right, better be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 31):

Try:

```
BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()
```

Comment: @bahamut100: I recommend this answer over the accepted one. They are subtly different.

Comment: +1 too. Plus this one does not have a huge performance penalty as the number of rows grow (compared to the accepted answer which uses a function on a column used in `where`)...

Answer (score 3):

If `created_at` has an index and you wouldn't like to prevent the optimiser from using it, I would recommend the following pattern (assuming `created_at` contains both date and time):

```
WHERE created_at >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY
  AND created_at <  CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

This spans the range from the day exactly one week ago till today (inclusive), so 8 days in total.

Answer (score 0):

also have a look at MySQL functions ADDDATE(), DATE_ADD(), DATE_SUB()

e.g.

```
ADDDATE(DATE(NOW()), -7)
```