# Selecting A Date Between Another Field's Date and Other Date

Tags: sql, teradata

So, here's what I'm trying to accomplish - finding a date between an existing date and 30 days after.  My subquery code:

```
select sldate
from sldaterefret
group by sldate
having sldate between orig_sldate + 30
```

Hope that makes sense.  As always, thank you in advance.

Comment: To offer some background - this is to help find returns to a store within 30 days after the purchase.  Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do : "Between TODAY AND TODAY-7"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276683/how-to-do-between-today-and-today-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select sldate

from sldaterefret

where sldate between orig_sldate and orig_sldate + 30

group by slate;

can you please try this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `AND` in your `BETWEEN` clause for proper functionality:

`HAVING sldate BETWEEN orig_sldate AND DATEADD(day, 30, orig_sldate)`

Something like that should do the trick for SQLServer, if this is MySQL it might look like

`HAVING sldate BETWEEN orig_sldate AND DATE_ADD(orig_sldate,INTERVAL 30 DAY)`